# Fedora CHECKSUM giving error in Windows

Tags: linux, fedora, verification

I've never used Fedora before this. I just downloaded the image from official website (Live Workstation 64bit). I downloaded the CHECKSUM as well. Now when I try to verify the CHECKSUM using the given method in the docs for [How to verify Fedora image on Windows](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/21/html/Installation_Guide/sect-verifying-images.html) it gives an error. 
Starting out, everything goes well, but when I enter this string:

```
 $download_checksum = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($sha256.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$PWD\$image"))).ToLower() -replace '-', ''
```

It gives this error:

```
Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."
At line:1 char:104
+ $download_checksum = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($sha256.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes <<<< ("$PWD\$
image"))).ToLower() -replace '-', ''
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I tried booting without verification, but it gives error something like `NOT A COM32 IMAGE`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115865/how-to-troubleshoot-system-outofmemoryexception-while-trying-to-install-fedora-o

According to this forum, the error is related to memory management in Windows. Instead of reading all ISO file into memory, this solution treats the ISO file as a stream in order to calculate the sha256sum.

Hope it helps!

Comment: please, copy the important part of the linked answer so it is helpful even without reading through all thread.

Answer (score 0):

as the a co-maintainer of the Fedora ISOs  I'd recommend  downloading QuickHash (link below and  use sha256 option with the ISO as the source file )

http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickhash/files/v2.6.1-Windows/

Also nice is that quickhash works on all platforms and computes/compares hashes from md5 thru sha512( used on live updated ISOs )

for the updated Live ISOs head to:

http://tinyurl.com/live-respins / http://tinyurl.com/live-torrents

OR

(my personal mirror) 
http://52.4.161.88/live-respins / http://52.4.161.88/live-torrents

the updated ISOs however DO USE sha512 checksums but with quickhash its a mere change in algorithm selection

Once on Fedora however  you can from a terminal (windows calls it powershell) run:

sha256(or 512)sum -c /path to Download directory used.

Feel free to reach out to me directly if needed here or  in the irc channels

http://chat.freenode.net/#fedora #fedora-devel #fedora-qa

I use the nick Corey84  there.

Comment: Thanks for replying with an authoritative answer. Just FYI, Super User's model is more akin to creating a textbook than a forum. Contact information is generally inappropriate in an answer because 1) the site isn't designed around personal interaction, it's a reference source; 2) the contact information is likely to become outdated; and 3) publishing it here could make you a spam target. You can put it in the website field on your profile if you want to share it, and invite contact in your "about me".

Comment: @fixer1234,  I am aware of that fact but as it is  updated regularly  in this case and  very related I am willing to take the risk.

Comment: also of note:  archive.org  is also populated with these same ISOs  on the second week of every month..